# WriteFile and Images /Links Path Issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

My main file is c:\Showblog.aspx that has the below code.

```
Response.WriteFile("c:\blog\blog1.htm", true);
```

The output display is unable to show the images and links due to the path issue. We are trying to get rid of IFRAME that we have been using so far. 
Thanks.

Comment: More information is needed. Are you saying the browser can't find the images referenced in blog1.htm? Can you show us the error (e.g. from Developer Tools in the browser)? What path is being used in the IMG tag? What folder are the images in? What URL is being shown in the browser? My guess is that the browser is trying to show file:///C:/Showblog.aspx but the images are in the blogs folder? This means the IMG tags should have a path of something like src="blogs/blah.jpg". The confusion stems from the fact that you are returning html from a sub-folder to the URL that is the parent.

Comment: You are right @Andrew. images are in blog folder as well as in other folders, so is the case with the hyperlinks. IFRAME took care of all this. We are trying to go responsive and HEARD and that IFRAME should be abandoned.